# Formatting guidelines for type aliases

Tags: python, python-3.10

What would be the correct way to format the name of a type alias—intended to be local to its module—according to the PEP8 style guide?

```
# mymodule.py
from typing import TypeAlias

mytype: TypeAlias = int

def f() -> mytype:
    return mytype()

def g() -> mytype:
    return mytype()
```

Should `mytype` be formatted in `CapWords` because it introduces a new type similar to creating new classes? Or, should `mytype` be formatted in all caps because it is treated similarly to a constant?

Is there a way to differentiate between type aliases that will remain unchanged (constant) throughout the lifetime of the program and ones that can change (similar to the `Final` annotation for constants)?

Also, should `mytype` be prefixed with an underscore (as in `_mytype`) to indicate that the type alias shouldn't be used outside this module?

Comment: Not sure why there's a close vote for being opinion-based. The question is about specific guidance from a specific style guide, and so it can be answered in a factual manner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The [PEP Style Guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) does *not* have any explicit guidance on how to format `TypeAlias`es.** The guide does contain [some rules on type variables](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#type-variable-names), but that's not quite what you're asking for.

---

The next best resource I could find was [Google's Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#3196-type-aliases), which does happen to contain some guidance on how to name `TypeAlias`es:

> **3.19.6 Type Aliases**
>
> You can declare aliases of complex types. The name of an alias should be CapWorded. If the alias is used only in this module, it should be _Private.
>
> For example, if the name of the module together with the name of the type is too long:
>
> ```py
> _ShortName = module_with_long_name.TypeWithLongName
> ComplexMap = Mapping[str, List[Tuple[int, int]]]
> ```
>
> Other examples are complex nested types and multiple return variables from a function (as a tuple).

Under this, the name of your type alias should be `MyType` if used across multiple modules, or `_MyType` if only used in the module that it is declared in.

---

With all of this being said, remember that **consistency with the existing codebase is what's most important**. As [the PEP style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) states:

> A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is the most important.